# Different page style on last page of chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design

I am using fancyhdr for the formatting of my page styles. I have used a headerline that expands inwards. On the first page of a chapter this line is shorter.

In a chapter it looks like this:
[image: in a chapter]

When a chapter opens I looks like this (this should be changed):
[image]

I want to change the above appearance of a double-page where a new chapter starts. The headerline should not be continued, as the content also makes a break. How can I introduce a shorter header line on the last page of the chapter?

I am also very open to any other design ideas to make a professional yet stylish page design of this book with 200+ pages.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
    DIV=12,
    parskip=half,
    bibtotocnumbered,
    paper=a4,
    BCOR=4mm,
    toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{21mm}
\fancyfootoffset[RO,LE]{10mm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{21mm}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{-0.2\textwidth}
\fancyfootoffset[RO,LE]{10mm}
}

\title{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap One}
\section{Section One-One}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chap Two}
\section{Section Two-One}
\Blindtext
\section{Section Two-Two}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are using a KOMA script class with scrbook, you should better work with `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fandyhdr`. Details can be found in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use `fancyhdr` and want to use your proposed design, here is how to do it.

I think the only reliable way to check if you are on the last page of a chapter, is to put a label on the start page of each chapter, and then check in `fancyhdr` whether the current page number is one less than the the start page of the next chapter. This must be done when processing the header, otherwise the page number might be incorrect.
You need an extra LaTeX run to get the labels correct.

So that is what the following code does. It doesn't work for the last page of the document, as there is no next chapter then, but you could add a fake start page label at the end of the document with `\AtEndDocument`.

```
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
    DIV=12,
    parskip=half,
    bibtotocnumbered,
    paper=a4,
    BCOR=4mm,
    toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[LO]{21mm}
\fancyfootoffset[RO,LE]{10mm}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textbf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{21mm}
\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{-0.2\textwidth}
\fancyfootoffset[RO,LE]{10mm}
}
\fancyheadinit{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{startpage-\thechapter}-1
    \fancyheadoffset[RE]{0mm}%
  \else
    \fancyheadoffset[RE]{21mm}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\prechapter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  % Set label. Chapter <n> gets label startpage-<n-1>
  \label{startpage-\thechapter}
}

% Prepend \prechapter to \chapter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\prechapter}{}{\error}

\title{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap One}
\section{Section One-One}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chap Two}
\section{Section Two-One}
\Blindtext
\section{Section Two-Two}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. You suggest to use scrlayer-scrpage instead, can the same commands used with this package?

Comment: I didn't suggest that. And I have no idea. You will have to read the koma-script documentation to find out. On the other hand, I think fancyhdr might work well.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a starting point using `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr` as you are using the KOMA-Script class `scrbook`. For further customization you can have a look at the [scrguide](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).

Following the rules of "good" typography, one does not change the style of the last page of a chapter either, but formats the chapter start pages in a different style. The chapter start pages usually have no header and the page numbering is placed in the middle of the bottom. There are also many notes on styling issues in the scrguide.

```
\documentclass[headsepline, DIV=12, BCOR=4mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

% define general style of header and footer
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark} 
\ifoot{\pagemark}

% define custom style for chapter pages
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{newChapterStyle}{\cfoot*{\pagemark} \ihead{} \ifoot{} \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}

% set custom style as chapter style
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{newChapterStyle}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not really answer my question aiming at a style that is not just the default. My style of having the headline extend inwards is not included in this answer. And also I wanted to place the page number outside of the text margin. I will use other elements in the page margin, too.